# How to set Bitmap image in Relative Layout background

Tags: android, xamarin

I have downloaded a bitmap from a url and now i wish to set it as a background for my relative layout.
this is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
     WebClient client = new WebClient ();
     client.DownloadDataAsync (new Uri (mItems [position].Profile_Pic));
     client.DownloadDataCompleted += (se, res) => {
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (res.Result, 0, res.Result.Length);
      var relativelayout=row.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.relativeLayout1);
```

how do i go about doing it?thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

You should use `BitmapDrawable`

```
var bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

...

relativelayout.SetBackground(bitmapDrawable);
//or
relativelayout.SetBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
//SetBackgroundDrawable deprecated in API level 16
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android way would be:

```
 relativelayout.setBackground(...);
```

for an int resource, or

```
 relativelayout.setBackgroundResource(...);
```

for  a drawable.

I'm sure you could find a Xamarin compliant method

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add a ImageView in your relativeLayout and get an instance of your imageView and try this :-

In your axml file :
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder"
            android:padding="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

In Code:

var imageView =row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img);
**img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);**
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once.

```
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(YOUR_BITMAP_SOURCE);
YOUR_LAYOUT.setBackground(background);
```